# Play images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I want to make the image animation using JavaScript with some controllable functionality, such as play, pause and stop, the following is so far I've tried:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Player</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        window.onload=function () {
            var rotator=document.getElementById("slideshow_content");
            var images=rotator.getElementsByTagName("img");
            for (var i=1; i<images.length; i++) {
                images[i].style.display="none";
            }
            var counter=1;
            setInterval(function () {
                for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
                    images[i].style.display="none";
                }
                images[counter].style.display="block";
                counter++;
                if (counter==images.length) {
                    counter=0;
                }
            }, 3000);

            function playimage() {
                player.play();
            }

            function pauseimage() {
                player.pause();
            }

            function stopimage() {
                player.pause();
                player.currentTime=0;

            }
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div id="slideshow_content" width="200px" height="200px" 
            style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <img alt="" src="a.jpg" />
            <img alt="" src="b.jpg" />
            <img alt="" src="c.jpg" />
            <img alt="" src="d.jpg" />
            <img alt="" src="e.jpg" />
            <img alt="" src="f.jpg" />
        </div>
        <button onclick="playimage()">
            Play</button><br />
        <button onclick="pauseimage()">
            Pause</button><br />
        <button onclick="stopimage()">
            Stop</button><br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work as expected, when I click on <kbd>start</kbd> button it doesn't not show me any image ..

How can I make it work, as when I click on the <kbd>start</kbd> button and the images could be played; when I click on <kbd>stop</kbd> and it could stop .. ?

What I'm doing wrong and where is the problem?

Comment: Check your javascript console and look for an error. For one thing, the `onclick` handler on the button is passing `element` but that variable is never defined. Did you mean `nextImage('element')`?

Comment: You missed 2 of right curly braces in your code. One is for `for-loop`, and the other is for function scope. (Of course, to correct this will not solve your problem .. )

Comment: @Chris plz see my updated code code works but when i debug images autmatically play and when i click on stop button it can not stop images..now i want when i debug then i click on play button then images will be play and when click on stop it must be stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and poor implementation .. :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Player</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function Player() {
            var rotator=document.getElementById('slideshow_content');
            var images=rotator.getElementsByTagName('img');
            var intervalID;
            var counter=1;

            function animate() {
                var i;

                for (i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
                    images[i].style.display='none';
                }

                images[counter].style.display='block';

                counter++;

                if (counter==images.length) {
                    counter=0;
                }
            }

            this.pause=function () {
                if (undefined!==intervalID) {
                    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
                    intervalID=undefined;
                }
            };

            this.stop=function () {
                this.pause();

                for (var i=1; i<images.length; i++) {
                    images[i].style.display='none';
                }
            };

            this.play=function () {
                if (undefined===intervalID) {
                    intervalID=window.setInterval(animate, 1000);
                }
            };

            this.stop();
            this.currentTime=0;
        }

    </script>
    <script>
        function playimage() {
            player.play();
        }

        function pauseimage() {
            player.pause();
        }

        function stopimage() {
            player.stop();
            player.currentTime=0;
        }

        function Page_Load() {
            player=new Player();
            player.play();
        }

        document.onreadystatechange=function () {
            if ('complete'==document.readyState) {
                Page_Load();
            }
        };

        var player; 

    </script>
    <div id='slideshow'>
        <div id='slideshow_content' width='200px' height='200px' style='padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;'>
            <img src='a.jpeg' />
            <img src='b.jpeg' />
            <img src='c.jpeg' />
            <img src='d.jpeg' />
        </div>
        <input type='button' value='Play' onclick='playimage();' />
        <input type='button' value='Pause' onclick='pauseimage();' />
        <input type='button' value='Stop' onclick='stopimage();' />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Some things to note:

1. Images are renamed for my testing, you will need to name them as your requirement.
2. You will need to ensure the elements you are using of the document are complete loaded.
3. `player` is involved in your code, but I've seen it nowhere, and I declared a `Player` class for creating the `player`.
4. Use a long text as the `code` argument of `setInterval` is a bad idea, I declared it a private function(`animate`) instead.
5. Read carefully how the `play`, `pause` and `stop` is implemented within the code.
6. I have no idea what `currentTime` is used for, just stay with it.

Comment: what do u mean by poor implementation

Comment: @MysimpleWorld: What I meant is that I did not design it well in a good pattern, and simply wrote workable code ..